# Is it possible to apply stable diffusion to text?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, text-generation

Is it possible in theory to apply Stable Diffusion to a text domain?

I'm trying to generate text using a Seq2Seq approach, and I'm wondering whether or not it's possible to apply stable diffusion by making use of a convolutional Seq2Seq model.

Answer (score 1):

https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.08933 is designed for the seq2seq text generation tasks using diffusion models.